# Идентификатор для Google chars элементов

Tags: javascript

Нужен максимально простой чарт, но что бы при клике на какой либо из его элементов, я смог повесить обработчик клика, и по нужным данным, например название в Label, дальше уже делать что мне нужно, с гугловской библиотекой такое осуществимо? Я просмотрел 10 самых популярных библиотек, но такой опции я так и не нашел. Если у кого опыт?

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

GoogleChart документация, если я правильно понимаю вопрос, то все ответы тут
в частности в selectHandler()

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_interactivity